# A WP form plugin that can set predefine fields when click on link

Tags: wordpress, forms

I have a page with all the course description (Course 101, 102, 103)

For each course description, there will be a link that says "Sign up for this course"

User clicks on the link (let say for Course 101) and it will direct to the sign up form with Course 101 already selected.

Does anyone know if any form plugins can do that? I am currently using Ninja Forms.

Thanks!